# Highlight whole line (from left border to right border) in Emacs' regexp mechanism

Tags: regex, emacs, highlight

I'm using

```
(highlight-regexp ".*data id=\"[^\"]*\".*" 'hi-green)
```

to highlight lines containing some regexp (`data id="..."`), but it only does so from the *left window border* to the **last char in the line**.

How to get the whole line highlighted, up to the **right window border**?

UPDATE -- I do need to have some highlights on the whole line, others not:

```
;; whole line
(highlight-regexp ".*data id=\"[^\"]*\".*" 'hi-green)
(highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".*panel.* id=\"[^\"]*\".*" 'hi-blue)

;; part of the line
(highlight-regexp "data=\"[^\"]*\"" 'hi-green)
(highlight-regexp "action id=\"[^\"]*\"" 'hi-pink)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't *think* this is possible using the font-lock mechanism, which `highlight-regexp` uses when `font-lock-mode` is active.  However, `highlight-regexp` falls back to using overlays otherwise, and the region of the overlays can be modified to include the whole visible line.

This behaviour can be forced around calls to `hi-lock-set-pattern` with the following advice,

```
(define-advice hi-lock-set-pattern (:around (orig &rest args) "whole-line")
  (let (font-lock-mode)
    (cl-letf* ((orig-make-overlay (symbol-function 'make-overlay))
               ((symbol-function 'make-overlay)
                (lambda (&rest _args)
                  (funcall orig-make-overlay
                           (line-beginning-position) ; could start from match
                           (line-beginning-position 2)))))
      (apply orig args))))
```

Comment follow-up: to only highlight entire visible lines when calling `highlight-regexp` and the regexp ends with `.*`, you could use the following (don't use the previous advice)

```
(define-advice highlight-regexp (:around (orig regexp &rest args) "maybe-whole-line")
  (if (string-suffix-p ".*" regexp)
      ;; use modified overlay bounds
      (let (font-lock-mode)
        (cl-letf* ((orig-make-overlay (symbol-function 'make-overlay))
                   ((symbol-function 'make-overlay)
                    (lambda (&rest _args)
                      (funcall orig-make-overlay
                               (line-beginning-position) ; could start from match
                               (line-beginning-position 2)))))
          (apply orig regexp args)))
    (apply orig regexp args)))
```

Comment: I tested it, and this is clearly the way to go, with one exception: it does highlight the whole line of regexps, while I need to have some of them with the whole line (the ones which mark kind of sections), and the others only for from a certain point in the line to an end point (now, they are fully highlighted). Is it possible to get both?

Comment: it's definitely possible -- for example, you could add your extended behaviour by checking if the regexp ends with `.*`, and use the modified overlay bounds, otherwise use the match bounds

Comment: Well over my current Lisp knowledge… ;-(

Comment: It did work when I first added it to my running Emacs. Now that it's restarted, it does not highlight anymore up to the right end of the screen.

Comment: Adding my regexps in the question.

Comment: Giving you already the point - for your work, and almost finished solution!  Thx!!

Comment: OK - found it. Works if I replace `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` by `highlight-regexp`.